# What exactly is this segment of code doing?

Tags: java

```
if (args.length == 3) {
        displayMode = new DisplayMode(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),
                Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Integer.parseInt(args[2]),
                DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    } else {
        displayMode = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16,
                DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    }
```

it appears as though `DisplayMode()` takes in 4 parameters, (3 integers and (something else))

but what exactly is `args[1]`?

I don't understand why you have to parse it as an integer?

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Is this from a `main` method?

Comment: `DisplayMode` probably takes integer values in its constructor. `args` is a String array and any integer represented as a String in the array must be parsed before sending it over to `DisplayMode` using the right type.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the `main(String[] args)` of a java function then
`args[1]` is a `String`. You have to parse `args[1]` with Integer.parseInt to get its integer value if it is an `integer` anyway.

`args[1]` is a command line argument and the program expects it to exist.
It is the second command line argument to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your previous question (regarding frame size issue 600x800 vs 800x600), so with that context, you need to provide integers as parameters on first and second arguments.

In java the main method has a signature like

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

The args contains all the argument which are passed as command line parameters

so if you run

```
java <yourclassname> 200 400 300
```

args[0] will contain "200" as a string, args[1] will contain "400" as string and so on

to convert these numbers and pass it to your class you will have to use Integer.parseInt

Answer (score 0):

You can pass command line arguments to a Java program when you run it. The following program would print `[1, 2, 3]` if invoked with `java ArgumentTest 1 2 3`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArgumentTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

However, since the arguments are all `String`s, you need to parse them to get other data types.